# Sync Core Data across Devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

Hey at the moment I'm learning Swift and started to create an App for that. Everything is fine and I think I know the basics now. In that App, I use CoreData to save my Data but I would like to Sync that across Devices

Is there a way with Icloud to do that, I found there is something called "[Core Data Ensembles](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles)" But is there a better way, or should I use the IcloudKit, if I can do the same things in IcloudKit with the relations like in coreData.

I just found old posts about that, so maybe there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such synchronization works without any libraries involved. The main trick here is to place SQL file (or whatever you use for storing data) into a special folder that is going to be synced, so-called ubiquity container, and specify path to it for your persistent store coordinator. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html) you can check high-level description of how it works, and there are a lot of step-by-step tutorials about it, e.g. [here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-6-tutorial-syncing-coredata-across-devices-using-icloud).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer I will give it a try.

Comment: @Coder221 It still works. It's only deprecated because it isn't for all storage needs.